# How to Run Two queries in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, function, stored-procedures

I have two tables `budged` and `adjustbud`

I want to create a stored procedure where I adjust the amount in `budged` table and same time the amount will be enter in `adjustbud` table.

Like

```
select amount 
from budged table 
where id = 1
```

then the result will be stored in a variable like this `@amt = amount`

After that the adjustable amount will be minus from the @amt and  the minus amount will be update in `budged` table.

Comment: Are you saying you want this to happen when the amount in budged table is amended or a SP to amend budged table?

Comment: Why not make this a bit simpler? Just insert the audit row first and then update the Budgeted table.